# Is there a name for how console.log formats the Json object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

When a json object is printed, for ex in a script executed by node using console.log, it does not fully pretty print the json. It kind of takes middle ground and prints as few lines as possible without losing much in terms of readability.

I was wondering if there is any name for this formatting or an algorithm. I want to implement this formatting in other languages.

Comment: Did you mean JSON string, or JavaScript Object? JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation, so JSON Object doesn't make much sense. I think you're referring to the formatting of node.js's `console.log` output when passed an object, am I correct?

Comment: Name? Doubt it.... Look at the node's source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log` in Node.js is basically this:

```
(value, ...args) => process.stdout.write(util.format(value, ...args) + '\n')
```

From the documentation on `util.format`:

> If the first argument is not a string then `util.format()` returns a string that is the concatenation of all arguments separated by spaces. Each argument is converted to a string using `util.inspect()`.
>
> <sup>- https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args</sup>

Which means that `console.log(object)` is equivalent to:

```
> process.stdout.write(util.inspect(object) + '\n');
```

From the documentation on `util.inspect`:

> The `util.inspect()` method returns a string representation of object that is intended for debugging. The output of `util.inspect` may change at any time and should not be depended upon programmatically. Additional options may be passed that alter certain aspects of the formatted string. `util.inspect()` will use the constructor's name and/or @@toStringTag to make an identifiable tag for an inspected value.
>
> <sup>- https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_showhidden_depth_colors</sup>

As far as I can tell there is no "name" for the default formatting settings of `util.inspect`, other than "compact" as mentioned (a boolean option that is set to true by default) by the `util.inspect` documentation.